# Penalty method for $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + 2y^2 + z^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

**Exercise :**

> Given the constraints $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 9, \; \; x+ y = 1, \; \; x-y = 2$ find a sufficient penalty function. Then, construct a penalty function for the minimization optimization problem of the function $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + 2y^2 + z^2$ over the constraints given.

**Attempt :**

The penalty function $p(x)$ will be given as :

$$p(x) = \max\{0, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 9\}^2$$

How would one construct a penalty function for the minimization problem of the $f(x,y,z)$ given ?

Comment: If $x+y=1$ and $x-y=2$ then $x=\frac 32, y=-\frac 12$.

Comment: @lulu True. But how must I construct the penalty function for $f(x,y,z)$ then ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are looking for.  There is only one point!  That tends to make optimization pretty straight forward.

Comment: A penalty is $\alpha(\vec x)=p(\vec x)+(x+y-1)^2+(x-y-2)^2$. It should be added to $f$ as $f(\vec x)+\mu\alpha(\vec  x)$ and optimized over $\vec x$ for larger $\mu$.

Comment: if $x+y = 1$ and $x-y = 2$ are your constraints as strict equalities and not as inequalites then  $\frac 32^2+ \frac 12^2 + z^2 \le 9$ or $|z| \le \frac {\sqrt {26}}{2}$

Comment: @A.Γ.  correct . however I would prefer  $p^2 (x)$ instead of $p(x)$.

Comment: @Redshoes It is already squared in $p(x)$. Another square would slow down the convergence as $p^2\ll p<1$ will penalize less.

Comment: Oh .. didn't see that "2". I see @A.Γ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the barrier function technique (Fiacco-Mc Cormick) a good barrier formulation could be

$$
\phi(x,y,z,\lambda)=x^2-2 y^2+z^2+\lambda_1\max \left(0,x^2+y^2+z^2-9\right)^2+\lambda_2(x+y-1)^2+\lambda_3 (x-y-2)^2
$$

Here $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ are positive constants adapted to each barrier to enhance the restriction satisfaction. The present exercise with $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=\lambda_0$ and calling

$$
f = x^2-2 y^2+z^2\\
g_1 = \max \left(0,x^2+y^2+z^2-9\right)^2\\
g_2 = (x+y-1)^2\\
g_3 = (x-y-2)^2
$$

gives after minimization a result which is $\lambda_0$ dependent.

$$
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
x & y & z & \lambda_0 & g_1 & g_2 & g_3 & f\\
 0.89668 & -2.89289 & 0 & 1 & 0.0298729 & 8.97726 & 3.20255 & -15.9336 \\
 1.42857 & -0.555556 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 0.016125 & 0.000251953 & 1.42353 \\
 1.49254 & -0.505051 & 0 & 100 & 0 & 0.00015658 & 0 & 1.71752 \\
 1.49925 & -0.500501 & 0 & 1000 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.74675 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Are you sure you implemented the $g_1$ correctly ?   Note that always $g_1 \ge 0 $

Comment: Thanks. Now it is fixed. Just a distraction.

Comment: May I know what software you used to generate this numbers ?

Comment: I used the function `NMinimize` from MATHEMATICA.

Comment: $g_1$ as it is (without square) is ill-conditioned (not differentiable). It is an exact penalty function that works well as a merit function to compute a step, but less good for any kind of (quasi)-Newton directions.

Comment: I agree with you. I will change the $g_1$ barrier squaring it to have smooth behavior. Thanks.